# How to find $X$ and $y$ that satisfies the following conditions?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Suppose that $\mathbf{x},\mathbf{y}\in\mathbb{R}^{10}$.
How can I find $\mathbf{x}$ and $\mathbf{y}$ for the following conditions:
$$ \mathbf{x}^T\mathbf{x}=1,\quad \mathbf{x}^T\mathbf{y}=5 \quad \text{and}\quad \mathbf{y}^T\mathbf{y}=26? $$

This is from the paper [The Bayesian Lasso](https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/epdf/10.1198/016214508000000337?needAccess=true) in Appendix B and I'm interested to replicate the same example.

Comment: I have edited the question to include this.

Comment: Notice $\| \mathbf{x}\|^2 = \mathbf{x}^T\mathbf{x}$ which leads to 
\begin{align*} 
x^2_1 + \cdots+x^2_{10} &= 1, \\
y^2_1 + \cdots+y^2_{10} &= 26, \\
x_1y_1 + \cdots+x_{10}y_{10} &= 5. 
\end{align*}.

Comment: There will be infinitely many solutions. Given any unit vector $\mathbf{x}$ of your choice, each $\mathbf{y} = 5\mathbf{x} + \widehat{\mathbf{x}}$ will satisfy the conditions where $\widehat{\mathbf{x}}$ is a unit perpendicular to $\mathbf{x}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can be helpful to just try things and see if they work.

Let's start with the condition: $x^T x = 1$ and (somewhat arbitrarily) pick $x = [1, 0, ..., 0]^T$. You can verify that $x^T x = 1$ with this $x$.

Now, we move to the second condition. To get $x^T y = 5$ we know we need $y = [5, ...]^T$ (the first entry is $5$). This satisfies the second condition.

So, we move to the third condition. We need $y^Ty = 26$. If we stopped at $y = [5, 0, ..., 0]$ we would get $y^T y= 25$. To get to $26$, we can make $y = [5, 1, 0, ..., 0]$ and, boom, we're done.

A lot of times, just trying *something* will help make progress. It can be a good exercise to come up with some different solutions to the question.

Comment: @CroCo nice catch, just fixed it. Thanks!